# Resume activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, resume, onstart

I have an app with 3 activities.

I have the main activity. This calls the second activity, which then calls the third activity. I want return to the main activity without entering the onCreate.

This is the code for the third activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(TerceraActiviry.this, Main.class));
```

Comment: use launchMode singleTop

Comment: singleTop will only re-use the same instance if an instance is already on top of the activity stack, which in this case it won't be

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If your `Activity` is still running, this code will bring it to the front without entering `onCreate`

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(TerceraActiviry.this, Main.class);
openMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivityIfNeeded(openMainActivity, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I search this solution during many hours. And you solved in a minutes.

Comment: I think there is 1 extra " ) " in first line.

Answer (score 4):

in order to get back to previous Activity you have to finish the visible one, use this:

```
finish();
```

If the activity was started for a result, you should give a result then, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(KEY_RESPONSE, responseData);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And you should catch the result on the caller Activity using:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  switch (requestCode) {
    // Test for the code you have used to start the Activity
  }
}
```

Hope it helps, 
Regards

Comment: I found this finish() as the best option, if you are not planning to return to the current activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.

refer the android dev for more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Comment: I don't agree - this will still create a new instance of the activity

Comment: if you use startActivityForResult to start the second and third activities, you can return to the first activity by setting RESULT_OK and calling finish() method (respectively). There by passing control back to the already existing main activity.

Comment: Fair point - in the context of the question it looked like you were suggesting that he replace the startActivity with startActivityForResult, which wouldn't have helped

Comment: Thats why i provided a link which gives a more detailed answer since its a very basic question.

Answer (score 1):

The launch mode flag you want is clearTop. This will go back to the previous instance of the main activity and clear the second and third activity off the activity stack. For example, to do this from the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TerceraActiviry.this, Main.class));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this will call onCreate for the main activity