# I want to open the new activity from the listview for the contacts but not new activity for every value on the Array because it's a contacts

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I want to open the new `activity` from the `listview` for the `contacts` but not new `activity` for every value on the `Array` because it's a contacts

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent x = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    x.putExtra("selected", i);
    startActivity(x);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specefic problem

Comment: Do you mean resuming an activity? See this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408719/resume-activity-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408719/resume-activity-in-android).