# Android Firebase Push notification restarts app when clicked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

When receiving a Firebase push notification, while the App is backgrounded, Firebase automatically displays a notification.

The pending Intent included in this notification seems to always include the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, which will cause the App to be restarted when the notification is clicked, even if the App is already alive in the background.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and simply have `onNewIntent(intent)` on the main Activity invoked instead?

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409215/2750743

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `launchMode` attribute of the activity affects how the activity is launched.

see:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

`singleTop`, `singleTask`, or `singleInstance` should be used to prevent the notification intent from creating a new activity instance.

The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` doesn't influence a new activity being created, but makes the launched activity the root of a new task.

see:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

and:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Shawn, you're absolutely right. I completely forgot to set the launchMode. Thanks :-)

Comment: I had a similar problem with react-native and react-native-splash-screen. If someone else is also experiencing this, try setting the launch mode of the splash screen activity to singleInstance. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

in `AndroidManifest.xml` set your Activity `launchMode` to `singleTask` should fix this:

```xml
<activity
  ......
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  >
```

Comment: thanks , is so useful  explain directly how to implement the fix.