# How to resume activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create my own Alarm Android application. I want to achieve that when alarm is triggered, MainActivity is resumed (**not created again**). It basically means that if I set alarm and leave my application, I want that application to be resumed when alarm is triggered.

Currently, I am facing a problem that when alarm is triggered while my application runs in background and I click on application icon, onCreate method is called and basically two instances of application are running simultaneously (I have used Toast messages to confirm this). I expected that click on application icon will cause its resuming if it is already running in background, but it seems it is not the case.

Also, I have tried procedure explained here: [Resume activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408719/resume-activity-in-android) but it didn't work for me, Toast message from onCreate method appears on screen.

Can anybody help, please? I am really running out of ideas here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "click application icon" where?
And if by that you only mean sending it to background and re-opening it then it has nothing to do with your alarm service probably.

Comment: Ivan, thank you for answer. By clicking application icon, I meant clicking on this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12xogGgJ0z2oMc6b9UuMEI2JhxD6ORY-g/view?usp=drivesdk In other words, I meant exactly what you wrote: sending it to background after setting alarm time and reopening it when alarm triggers

Comment: You can use `singleInstance` launch mode, but the fact that your app wasn't killed to reclaim memory cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: EpicPandaForce, thank you for your answer. I have tried, but unfortunately, it doesn't change anything - onCreate method is called again when I reopen application. Instead of resuming, application is started again, so two instances of application are running in parallel. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is specify your activity's launch mode to `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. To do this, go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and change/add launchMode to your activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="Your Activity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

More info on the differences of different launch modes are explained here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

Comment: noahutz, thank you for answer. I've just tried with singleInstance and after that with singleTask and unfortunately, the behavior is the same - I see that onCreate method is called again and I notice that two instances of app are running simultaneously. Any other suggestion?